# How to add time in 12-hours format to filename using Windows command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to have filename with hours in 12-hours format - from 1 to 12 (with am or pm optional) like below:

```
myfile_2pm.txt
```

I wrote script but it works only for 24-hours format and crashes if it has "1-digit" hour because colon:

```
Hello > myfile_%time:~-0,2%.txt
```

Comment: if you could describe more what is you are trying to achieve ? that is what is the situation where you would need file name like this, that might help knowing situation better

Comment: I need to create file with name which includes current hour in 12-hours format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    call :get12h hour
    echo %hour%

    echo This is a test > myfile_%hour%.txt

    exit /b

:get12h outputVar
    setlocal enableextensions
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=: " %%a in ("%time: =0%") do set /a "h=1%%a-100"
    if %h% gtr 11 ( 
        set "td=pm" & if %h% gtr 12 set /a "h-=12"
    ) else ( 
        set "td=am" & if %h% equ 0 set "h=12"
    )
    endlocal & set "%~1=%h%%td%" & exit /b
```

This uses a subroutine that when called returns the current time in 12h format in the variable used as argument. Return value will be in the range

```
12am , 1am , .... 12pm, 1pm, .... 11pm
```

Comment: +1, I'm wondering if a machine could be configured so `%TIME%` returns zero prefixed hours, such that 9am would appear as `09:00:00.00`. I haven't seen it, but if it happens then your code will break because 09 is invalid octal notation.

Answer (score 1):

don't know about am / pm but for single digit
try putting <kbd>" "</kbd>, i.e. enclose the command with double quotes should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
set hr=%time:~0,2%
set hr=%hr: =0%
```

Then use `%hr%` inside whatever string you are formatting to always get a 2-digit hour.

Answer (score 1):

MC ND has a good simple solution using pure batch. But it is very specific to your exact requirements.

Working with date and time on Windows batch is painful, especially if you want a solution that works with any locale, given that the format of `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` varies between machines.

I have written a handy [hybrid JScript/batch utility called getTimestamp.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847) that performs date and time computations and formatting. It can handle nearly any date/time computation or formatting task you are likely to have. The utility is pure script that runs natively on any modern Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script.

Assuming getTimestamp.bat is in your current directory, or better yet, somewhere within your PATH, then the following will store the current hour using your format in the `hr` variable:

```
call getTimestamp -f _{h}{pm} -r hr
```